# Entity-framework The column name is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT

Tags: entity-framework, collections, foreign-keys, asp.net-core-3.1

I have entity

```
public class ImageTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public int PostTeamID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int ImageType { get; set; }
    public int StatusPublic { get; set; }
    public int StatusActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NoMember { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
    public int StatusActive { get; set; }
    public int TeamType { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TeamGroup> ListMember { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ImageTeam> ListAvatar { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ImageTeam> ListBanner { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

---

config data context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasMany(x => x.ListAvatar)
            .WithOne(t => t.Team)
            .HasForeignKey(pv => pv.TeamID);
});
```

when I post the data insert a new record entity ImageTeam [then it show exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEDAc.png)

I need to do...Help me

Answer (score 0):

In the Team class you add another relation `ListBanner` to ImageTeam class ,you have not set an foreign key for it, so EF automatically creates a TeamID and because TeamId already in the class, it's throw exception . You also need to set an foreign key for second relation.

```
public class ImageTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public int BannerTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team BannerTeam { get; set; }
    public int PostTeamID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int ImageType { get; set; }
    public int StatusPublic { get; set; }
    public int StatusActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

}

 entity.HasMany(x => x.ListAvatar)
                .WithOne(t => t.Team)
                .HasForeignKey(pv => pv.TeamID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            entity.HasMany(x => x.ListBanner)
                .WithOne(t => t.BannerTeam)
                .HasForeignKey(pv => pv.BannerTeamId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
ImageType more than 2 : [ avatar, banner, post, story...]
collections ImageTeam use together a TeamID foreign key.

Comment: Each relationship must have its own foreign key and cannot be shared with others.for mor information [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
edit Team entity:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NoMember { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
    public int StatusActive { get; set; }
    public int TeamType { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TeamGroup> ListMember { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ImageTeam> ListImage { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

}
```

*no config data context

create new model: TeamViewModel

```
public class TeamViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int NoMember { get; set; }
        public float Score { get; set; }
        public int StatusActive { get; set; }
        public int TeamType { get; set; }
        public virtual List<TeamGroupViewModel> ListMember { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ImageTeam> ListImage { get; set; }
        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ImageTeam> ListAvatar { get; set; }
        public string BannerUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ImageTeam> ListBanner { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ImageTeam> ListPost { get; set; }
    }
```

in controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/{id}/view")]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetById(int id)
{
    var team = _teamService.GetById(id);
    var model = _mapper.Map<TeamViewModel>(team);
    model = parserImageTeam(model);
    return Ok(model);
}

[Route("api/[controller]/{UserId}/view-teams")]
[HttpGet("{UserId}")]
public IActionResult GetAllTeamOfUser(int UserId)
{
    // list teams
    var teams = _teamService.GetTeamOfUser(UserId);
    var _teams = _mapper.Map<IList<TeamViewModel>>(teams);
    var newTeams = new List<TeamViewModel>();
    foreach (TeamViewModel team in _teams)
    {
        newTeams.Add(parserImageTeam(team));
    }
    return Ok(newTeams);
}

private TeamViewModel parserImageTeam(TeamViewModel teamModel)
{
    var imageAvatars = new List<ImageTeam>();
    var imageBanners = new List<ImageTeam>();
    var imagePosts = new List<ImageTeam>();
    bool avt = false, banner = false;
    foreach (ImageTeam image in teamModel.ListImage)
    {
        if (image.ImageType == Constants.ImageType.IMAGE_AVATAR_TEAM)
        {
            image.Image = parserUrlImage(image);
            imageAvatars.Add(image);
            if (!avt)
            {
                teamModel.AvatarUrl = image.Image;
                avt = true;
            }

        }
        if (image.ImageType == Constants.ImageType.IMAGE_BANNER_TEAM)
        {
            image.Image = parserUrlImage(image);
            imageBanners.Add(image);
            if (!banner)
            {
                teamModel.BannerUrl = image.Image;
                banner = true;
            }

        }
        if (image.ImageType == Constants.ImageType.IMAGE_POST_TEAM)
        {
            image.Image = parserUrlImage(image);
            imagePosts.Add(image);
            banner = true;

        }
    }
    teamModel.ListAvatar = imageAvatars;
    teamModel.ListBanner = imageBanners;
    teamModel.ListPost = imagePosts;
    return teamModel;
}
private string parserUrlImage(ImageTeam model)
{
    string url = Configuration.GetValue<string>("BaseVariables:BaseUrl");
    // another controller handle request (ImagesController)
    return model.Image = url + "/Images/" + Constants.ImageType.getFolderName(model.ImageType).ToLower() + "/" + model.TeamID + "?ImageType=" + model.ImageType + "&imageName=" + model.Image;
}
```